# [Beamer/Latex]: Getting \part name from different part

Tags: latex, beamer

Hi I would like to create some sort of my own table of content in beamer presentation where there will be all parts with all sections listed.

To this moment I came up with this solution to list all \tableofcontents in one slide

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
        \foreach\x in {1,...,\totvalue{part}}{%
            \vskip 0.4cm
            \tableofcontents[part=\x]%
        }%
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \end{multicols}
\end{frame}
```

Problem here is that I get section of each part but there is not partname listed.

Is there way how to access name of part by index \x of for-cycle? Something like \insertpart[\x]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok with help of one co-student of mine I came up with solution to my problem.

```
\makeatletter
    \AtBeginPart{
        \write\@auxout{%
        \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\gdef\noexpand\csname
        part\thepart name\noexpand\endcsname{\beamer@partname}}
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \frame{\maketitle}

    \section*{Outline}
    \begin{frame}{Outline of Presentation}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
            \foreach\x in {1,...,\totvalue{part}}{%
                 \medskip\expandafter\let\expandafter\partname
                 \csname part\x name\endcsname
                 \penalty-999
                 \textit{\partname}
                 \medskip
                 {\let\vfill=\relax\tableofcontents[part=\x]}\vfill
                 \penalty-999
            }%
            \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{frame}
```

Unfortunately I cannot write down deep description of how exactly it works but basically it takes names of parts during first run of pdflatex and saves them into .aux file. Then during second run of pdflatex it will correctly print them out. Then negative penalty is added to each block so partname is not splitted out of rest of part-toc.

So two runs of pdflatex are needed to work it correctly but it should work quite nicely. I managed to create table of content with 4 parts.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByZLj.png)

Hopefully it will help someone.